# How do I level a hardwood floor with minimal damage?

Tags: hardwood-floor, sound-proofing, self-leveling-concrete

I'd like to soundproof my living room floor in order to minimize impact from footfall and airborne sound transmission from a piano. My general plan is to install soundproofing mats on top of the existing floor (hopefully as a floating layer), then glue on a new hardwood floor on top of that.

The soundproofing mats I'm looking at are [here](https://www.wolf-bavaria.com/produkt%C3%BCbersicht/phonestar-schallschutz/bhs/) (German). They're basically a series of cardboard layers with special sand in between. Looking at the instructions, they seem to have a very strict level tolerance of 3 mm every 2 meters. My current hardwood floor is old and is sagging in some areas (I notice at least one dip that's about 8 mm per meter).

Is there a way of levelling out the hardwood floor in order to lay the mats without pouring self-levelling compound? I would prefer to keep the original floor intact (it's original oak), just in case the next buyer wants to restore it. Could I put down a very thin layer of something between the current hardwood and the levelling compound so they don't directly touch? If not, would sanding be a viable option?

Comment: What? Ok we have hard wood you want a noise insulation and some kind of new ? Laminate that is glued together,,,, but wait for some reason the floor is not level and I don’t want to damage the original hard wood and it needs to be leveled? 
Am I right did you just ask this? This sounds like a job for “carpet man” able to fix any flirting problems in a single bound,,, ok sorry but a proper question may be how to isolate noise on a solid wood floor.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear. I have a hardwood floor right now that I want to soundproof. In order to lay soundproofing floor mats (made out of corrugated cardboard) the subfloor needs to be perfectly flat, so I either need to sand or use compound.

However, the next buyer *might* want the original floor. I was wondering if it's possible to level the hardwood without damaging it, so that if I needed to pull up all the soundproofing mats and new floor, the original would be usable.

Comment: Is there a basement underneath? If so, you can likely make considerable improvements with shims or possibly even just making some adjustments to existing posts.